# Formatting statsmodels regression parameters to a text string to obtain the fitted equation

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to build a text string with the fitted parameters of a statsmodel results screen. So far I've gotten to this:

```
results.params

const    18.352876
x         2.729230
x^2      -0.284947
x^3       0.017321
x^4      -0.000359
dtype: float64

"".join(['{coef}{var}+'.format(coef=i, var=j) for i,j in zip(results.params.values,results.params.index.values)])

'18.35287604545434const+2.7292297979902465x+-0.2849465918536549x^2+0.017320680602094476x^3+-0.00035853905617123927x^4+'
```

This is the best I can do with my current and limited knowledge, but there is obviously room for improvement.

Is there a better way to achieve a more elegant result, for example y=-3.59E-4x^4 +0.017x^3 -0.285x^2 +2.729x +18.353 using a built-in method from statsmodels or an improved  version of the above code? My goal is to get a string I can use as a title or name for a plotly trace

Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format your strings as follow `f'{i:.2E}{j}+'` and get them display in scientific notation

Comment: Thank you! I did this

```'y='+"".join([' {:+.3}{}'.format(i,j) for i,j in zip(results.params[::-1].values,results.params[::-1].index.values)]).strip('const') ```

and got this
```'y= -0.000359x^4 +0.0173x^3 -0.285x^2 +2.73x +18.4'```

Now I'm trying to put this string  on a plotly trace name like this

```fitname = '$y='+"".join([' {:+.3}{}'.format(i,j) for i,j in zip(results.params[::-1].values,results.params[::-1].index.values)]).strip('const')+'$'```

but the legend box doesn't show the complete text, need to figure out why.